# Drag and drop between two SVG charts using watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to perform drag and drop between two SVG charts which has g tag.Is it possible to perform using watir-webdriver.

Comment: Without your code or URL I can't test this myself, and I don't know anything about SVG, but try implementing Solution 2 from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713102/how-do-i-locate-a-custom-tag-like-g and see if you can do something like  `browser.g(:id, 'my_id').drag_and_drop_by 50, 50`. Not sure what technologies you are using, so I don't know if this will work or not, but it can't hurt to try that Solution 2.

Answer (score 1):

dragging and dropping is possible in watir.

Haven't tested this, but here's how it might work. (used the css selector b/c I'm not sure whether or not watir supports the `g` tag on a object-level basis...)

```
chart1 = browser.element(:css => "g[id='chart1']")
chart2 = browser.element(:css => "g[id='chart2']")
chart1.drag_and_drop_on(chart2)
```

Let me know if this works for you

Credits to similar question: [Is drag-and-drop possible in watir-webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503704/is-drag-and-drop-possible-in-watir-webdriver)